# COUNTIFS in a spreadsheet while ignoring duplicates in a separate column

Tags: excel, if-statement, count, duplicates

I'd like to find how to use the COUNTIFS function in excel to count the rows in a spreadsheet while ignoring duplicate values in a separate column. Here is a sample of the data:

[[image: Sample data in pastable format below]]

I would like to count the number of rows that are "One" on status and "Blue" on category. However, I only want to count the duplicates for these respective values in "ID" once.

Here's what I've tried:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY($A$2:$A$12,$A$2:$A$12)>0,1))
```

Same problem as the previous example. - this works for giving me the number of duplicates in column A, but I can't work any IF statements in effectively.

```
=IF(B2:B12="One",IF(C2:C12="Blue",SUM(IF(FREQUENCY($A$2:$A$12,$A$2:$A$12)>0,1))))
```

When I add IF statements in, I get the same number as the earlier formula.

For your copy/pasting pleasure:

```
ID     Status  Category
1423    One     Blue
1423    One     Blue
1423    One     Red
5124    One     Blue
5124    One     Blue
2341    Two     Blue
1111    One     Red
1212    Two     Red
1212    One     Blue
1111    One     Red
5124    One     Red
```

The ideal result would be **3**.

Comment: Your sample data does not have any duplicates that contain both One and Blue? Can you post a better data set as text or in a google sheet?

Comment: @AdamB So sorry, I corrected the example. I made a mock up file and must have been so flustered I flubbed it ;).

Comment: Can you put it somewhere we can cut and paste the sample data? The image means to test it we would need to retype an excel spreadsheet. You can just put it in the question.

Comment: Sure thing. Is that better @AdamB?

Comment: @Teller - You can use the [Remove Duplicates](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2) function. Then use a `Countifs`

Comment: @Teller Can you give further explain what a correct result would be on the data set you provided?

Comment: so... essentially you want a COUNTUNIQUE on three columns with conditions on 2...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a standard COUNTUNIQUE method using [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff) and [COUNTIF](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) functions; (e.g. `SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A2:A12, A2:A12&""))` ). This can be expanded to include conditions by changing to a [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED) but care must be made to ensure that no `#DIV/0!` error can occur.

In E4 as a standard formula,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((B2:B12="one")*(C2:C12="blue"))/(COUNTIFS(A2:A12, A2:A12, B2:B12, "one", C2:C12, "blue")+((B2:B12<>"one")+(C2:C12<>"blue"))))
```

The numerator of the division operation provides half of the conditional processing. The COUNTIFS denominator of the division operator must be the opposite (non-zero) of the numerator when the numerator is zero.

[image: countunnique_blue_red]

Comment: Can you replace `((B2:B12="one")*(C2:C12="blue"))` by `AND(B2:B12="one", C2:C12="blue")`? I find that would make it a bit more readable.